# How to return distance in "Km" using Google Distance Matrix API?

Tags: java, api, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I am using Google's Distance matrix API for Java.
I have properly working code but I want it to return distance between two latitude-longitude points (origin, destination) in Kilometers. But there's no such method or parameter that it takes to **return distance in kms**. ***However if the distance value is greater than or equal to 1km, it returns distance in km***. But i want it to return distance always in km **(for eg. 0.5 km)** but it always **returns distance in meters when distance is less than 1 km**. I tried to use `Unit.METRIC` also but its of no use as it still returns distance in meters only.

```
DistanceMatrix results =  DistanceMatrixApi.getDistanceMatrix(context, 
                    new String[] {origins}, new String[] {destinations}).units(Unit.METRIC).await();

results.rows[0].elements[0].distance //returns in meters, i want it in kms.
```

Comment: wouldn't divide by 1000 be good enough?

Comment: No, because I have seen some results and over google's distance matrix api documentation that they return distance values in "Kms"

example link here: [link][https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=40.6655101,-73.891889&destinations=40.6655101,-73.891009]

Comment: So it will all go wrong if at times The API returns distance already in Kms and I divide or multiply it by any figure (say 1000) as you suggested. I find it not the solution.

Comment: The documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro says that "this unit system setting only affects the text displayed within distance fields. The distance fields also contain values which are always expressed in meters."

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading google docs about distance matrix api, i finally came to conclusion that **the distance fields will contain "values" which are always expressed in meters.** So this value needs to be **divided by 1000** in order to get the value in "Kms".

Comment: This does no longer seem to be the case as i get value 0 returned when the distance is 1 meter

Answer (score 8):

From [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixResponses), you must just add the `units` parameter:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric
```